# test void method inside abstract anonymous class with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, abstract-class, anonymous-class

I am not able to test a method that is inside an abstract class instance. I have already tried several ways and would like to know if it is possible to do this. The contents of the abstract class can be seen in the link below.

[Jacoco Class Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QyFw.png)

Belows is the JUnit and Mockito test that I did trying to test the cases in the image above.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PahoRxMqttCallbackTest {

  @Test
  public void whenConnectionLostOccurs() {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = mock(PahoRxMqttCallback.class);
    assertThat(rxMqttCallback).isNotNull();

    PahoRxMqttException exception = new PahoRxMqttException(
        new MqttException(MqttException.REASON_CODE_CONNECTION_LOST));

    ArgumentCaptor<Throwable> onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Throwable.class);

    rxMqttCallback.connectionLost(exception);

    verify(rxMqttCallback).connectionLost(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isInstanceOf(PahoRxMqttException.class);
    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).hasCauseInstanceOf(MqttException.class);
    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(exception);
  }

  @Test
  public void whenConnectCompleteOccurs() {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = mock(PahoRxMqttCallback.class);
    assertThat(rxMqttCallback).isNotNull();

    boolean reconnect = true;
    String brokerUri = "tcp://localhost:1883";

    ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Boolean.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<String> onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

    rxMqttCallback.connectComplete(reconnect, brokerUri);

    verify(rxMqttCallback).connectComplete(
        onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor.capture(),
        onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(reconnect);
    assertThat(onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(brokerUri);
  }

  @Test
  public void whenDeliveryCompleteOccurs() {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = mock(PahoRxMqttCallback.class);
    assertThat(rxMqttCallback).isNotNull();

    IMqttDeliveryToken deliveryToken = mock(IMqttDeliveryToken.class);
    assertThat(deliveryToken).isNotNull();

    RxMqttToken rxMqttToken = new PahoRxMqttToken(deliveryToken);

    //ArgumentCaptor<IMqttDeliveryToken> onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(IMqttDeliveryToken.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<RxMqttToken> onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(RxMqttToken.class);

    //rxMqttCallback.deliveryComplete(deliveryToken);
    rxMqttCallback.deliveryComplete(rxMqttToken);

    /*
     * Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
     * Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
     */
    //verify(rxMqttCallback).deliveryComplete(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.capture());
    verify(rxMqttCallback).deliveryComplete(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.capture());

    //assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    //assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isExactlyInstanceOf(IMqttDeliveryToken.class);
    //assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(deliveryToken);

    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isExactlyInstanceOf(PahoRxMqttToken.class);
    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(rxMqttToken);
  }

  //@Test
  public void whenMessageArrived() throws Exception {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = mock(PahoRxMqttCallback.class);
    assertThat(rxMqttCallback).isNotNull();

    String topic = "topic";
    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();

    ArgumentCaptor<String> onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<MqttMessage> onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MqttMessage.class);

    rxMqttCallback.messageArrived(topic, message);

    /*
     * Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
     * Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
     */
    verify(rxMqttCallback).messageArrived(onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor.capture(), onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(topic);

    assertThat(onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(message);
  }

}
```

I really could not do it even after searching the web about it. So I appreciate the help.

**Update**

I was able to perform the tests and cover all the alerts that the Jacoco had shown. But for this I had to create an implementation for the abstract class rather than using anonymous class. As can be seen in the following link

[Jacoco Class Report 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej6Fq.png)

The updated unit tests:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PahoRxMqttCallbackTest {

  @Test
  public void whenConnectionLostOccurs() {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = spy(PahoRxMqttCallback.create(cause -> {}, (recon, uri) -> {}, t -> {}));

    PahoRxMqttException exception = new PahoRxMqttException(
        new MqttException(MqttException.REASON_CODE_CONNECTION_LOST));

    ArgumentCaptor<Throwable> onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Throwable.class);

    rxMqttCallback.connectionLost(exception);

    verify(rxMqttCallback).connectionLost(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isInstanceOf(PahoRxMqttException.class);
    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).hasCauseInstanceOf(MqttException.class);
    assertThat(onConnectionLostCauseArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(exception);
  }

  @Test
  public void whenConnectCompleteOccurs() {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = spy(PahoRxMqttCallback.create(cause -> {}, (r, u) -> {}, t -> {}));

    boolean reconnect = true;
    String brokerUri = "tcp://localhost:1883";

    ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Boolean.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<String> onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

    rxMqttCallback.connectComplete(reconnect, brokerUri);

    verify(rxMqttCallback).connectComplete(
        onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor.capture(),
        onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onConnectCompleteReconnectArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(reconnect);
    assertThat(onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onConnectCompleteServerUriArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(brokerUri);
  }

  @Test
  public void whenDeliveryCompleteOccurs() {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = spy(PahoRxMqttCallback.create(cause -> {}, (r, u) -> {}));

    IMqttDeliveryToken deliveryToken = new MqttDeliveryToken();

    RxMqttToken rxMqttToken = new PahoRxMqttToken(deliveryToken);

    ArgumentCaptor<IMqttDeliveryToken> onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(IMqttDeliveryToken.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<RxMqttToken> onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(RxMqttToken.class);

    rxMqttCallback.deliveryComplete(deliveryToken);
    rxMqttCallback.deliveryComplete(rxMqttToken);

    verify(rxMqttCallback).deliveryComplete(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.capture());
    verify(rxMqttCallback, times(2)).deliveryComplete(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isExactlyInstanceOf(MqttDeliveryToken.class);
    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(deliveryToken);

    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isExactlyInstanceOf(PahoRxMqttToken.class);
    assertThat(onDeliveryCompleteRxTokenArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(rxMqttToken);
  }

  @Test
  public void whenMessageArrived() throws Exception {
    PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = spy(PahoRxMqttCallback.create(cause -> {}, (r, u) -> {}, t -> {}));

    String topic = "topic";
    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();

    ArgumentCaptor<String> onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<MqttMessage> onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MqttMessage.class);

    rxMqttCallback.messageArrived(topic, message);

    verify(rxMqttCallback).messageArrived(onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor.capture(), onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onMessageArrivedTopicArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(topic);

    assertThat(onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(onMessageArrivedMessageArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(message);
  }

}
```

Comment: You posted here multiple tests but you forgot to show us the abstract class and the method you want to test. Also, which one of these tests is supposed to test this method?

Comment: @alfasin

The abstract class is represented in the image that can be accessed through the link above. (Jacoco Class Report). But if you want I can update the post by placing the content of the class in full. Basically, I want to test everything that is marked in red in the image available through the link, but in particular the method that starts at line 50 and ends at line 70. And to this I have created the test methods: whenConnectionLostOccurs, whenConnectCompleteOccurs and whenDeliveryCompleteOccurs respectively .

Comment: You should start by following a simple Mockito tutorial, before asking questions.

Comment: @tkruse Thanks for your comment but you should be a little gentler. I already read about the Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate the class, only mocks of the class.

```
 PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = mock(PahoRxMqttCallback.class);
```

A mock is not the real class, just a fake copy.

Instead you should do

```
 PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = new PahoRxMqttCallback();
```

or

```
 PahoRxMqttCallback rxMqttCallback = spy(new PahoRxMqttCallback());
```

Comment: I tried using real object, but the Mockito's verify method complained about it (org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument passed to verify() is of type and is not a mock). So, let's try use the spy() method instead. With this approach the test ran, but the Jacoco generated the report with the same warning as when I used the Mockito's mock method. Your answer is not wrong, but it was not the complete solution I had to do to solve my problem.